# heroku app runs OK remotely, but fails locally with "Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://username@localhost"

Tags: java, postgresql, gradle, heroku, hikaricp

i am trying to create a heroku app using gradle, java, springboot, postgres, and hikari.

i am following the documentation:

[Getting Started with Gradle on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-gradle-on-heroku?singlepage=true)

[Heroku Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql)

[Connecting to Relational Databases on Heroku with Java](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java)

i am using, without modification, the example git repo from the first link above:

```
https://github.com/heroku/gradle-getting-started.git
```

when i deploy the app to heroku, it functions correctly.  but when i try to run it locally it fails with `Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://username@localhost`.

i have tried monkeying every way that i can think of with settings, configuration, or environment variables, but so far i can't get it to work.

any idea what i'm doing wrong?  do i need to do something to deploy the JDBC locally?

if i do not set environment variable `JDBC_DATABASE_URL`, then this command...

```
./gradlew clean build
```

...completes successfully.  then if i do...

```
heroku local web
```

...the server starts up successfully.  when i browse to the endpoint below (which hits the database)...

```
http://localhost:5000/db
```

...it displays this error:

```
dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
```

by comparison, the same endpoint on the remote heroku server...

```
https://my_project_name.herokuapp.com/db
```

...displays this output:

```
Database Output
Read from DB: 2019-04-27 19:48:38.764037
Read from DB: 2019-04-27 19:58:30.007374
```

if i do...

```
export JDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://username@localhost
```

...then `gradlew clean build` fails with `Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://username@localhost`.  here is the full output:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'herokuApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.example.heroku.HerokuApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'herokuApplication' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://username@localhost
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.example.heroku.HerokuApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'herokuApplication' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://username@localhost
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'herokuApplication' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://username@localhost
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://username@localhost
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:112)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:336)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:109)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at com.example.heroku.HerokuApplication.dataSource(HerokuApplication.java:84)
    at com.example.heroku.HerokuApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f42e4dc5.CGLIB$dataSource$2(<generated>)
    at com.example.heroku.HerokuApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f42e4dc5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aca4e89.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at com.example.heroku.HerokuApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f42e4dc5.dataSource(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:298)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:104)
    ... 96 more
```

i am using, without modification, all of the code and configuration files from the example git repo mentioned above.

here are the contents of file `src/main/java/com/example/heroku/HerokuApplication.java`:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2002-2014 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.heroku;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class HerokuApplication {

  @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
  private String dbUrl;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(HerokuApplication.class, args);
  }

  @RequestMapping("/")
  String index() {
    return "index";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/db")
  String db(Map<String, Object> model) {
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
      Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
      stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticks (tick timestamp)");
      stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ticks VALUES (now())");
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT tick FROM ticks");

      ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
      while (rs.next()) {
        output.add("Read from DB: " + rs.getTimestamp("tick"));
      }

      model.put("records", output);
      return "db";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      model.put("message", e.getMessage());
      return "error";
    }
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    if (dbUrl == null || dbUrl.isEmpty()) {
      return new HikariDataSource();
    } else {
      HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
      config.setJdbcUrl(dbUrl);
      return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
  }

}
```

here are the contents of file `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL:}
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML

logging.level.org.springframework=INFO

spring.profiles.active=production

server.port=${PORT:5000}
```

here are the contents of file `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    runtimeOnly 'org.webjars:jquery:3.3.1-1'
    runtimeOnly 'org.webjars:jquery-ui:1.12.1'
    runtimeOnly 'org.webjars:bootstrap:4.1.3'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after an insane day of troubleshooting, i got it to work.  as near as i can tell, the commands `gradlew build` and `heroku local web` are only happy if the database user has a password.

by default when you install postgres on ubuntu you end up with a postgres account with the same name as your linux account, and with no password.

in my original attempts described in my OP above, i had some problems with the formatting of the values for environment variables `DATABASE_URL` and `JDBC_DATABASE_URL`.  once i fixed that, i started getting the error `The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided`, which i fixed by setting a password.

here are the steps that i followed:

1) set a password in postgres:

```
$psql
#alter user username with password 'password';
#\q
```

2) set the environment variables:

```
$export DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/username
$export JDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/username?user=username\&password=password
```

(i am specifying a database with the same name as my user name).
(the second `export` command contains the `&` character, which i must escape with a backslash).

3) build the project:

```
$./gradlew clean build
```

(you probably don't usually need the `clean` part, but at least once today i found the `clean` part necessary to reset some state).

4) start heroku local:

```
$heroku local web
```

5) browse to the endpoint that triggers a call to the database:

```
http://localhost:5000/db
```

this now displays the hoped-for output:

```
Database Output
Read from DB: 2019-04-27 19:48:38.764037
Read from DB: 2019-04-27 19:58:30.007374
```

whew!

Comment: Sir, you are a life saver. Thanks for taking the time to write this up.

Comment: Delighted to help :)